# How to design a scalable notification system?

Tags: design, architecture, performance, object-oriented-design, scalability

I need to write a notification system manager.

Here is my requirements:

I need to be able to send a Notification on different platforms, which may be totally different (for exemple, I need to be able to send either an SMS or an E-mail).

Sometimes the notification may be the same for all recipients for a given platform, but sometimes it may be a notification per recipients (or several) per platform.

Each notification can contain platform specific payload (for exemple an MMS can contains a sound or an image).

The system need to be **scalable**, I need to be able to send a very large amount of notification without crashing either the application or the server.

It is a two step process, first a customer may type a message and choose a platform to send to, and the notification(s) should be created to be processed either real-time either later.

Then the system needs to send the notification to the platform provider.

---

For now, I end up with some though but I don't know how scalable it will be or if it is a good design.

I've though of the following objects (in a pseudo language):

a generic `Notification` object:

```
class Notification {
    String                 $message;
    Payload                $payload;
    Collection<Recipient>  $recipients;
}
```

The problem with the following objects is what if I've 1.000.000 recipients ? Even if the `Recipient` object is very small, it'll take too much memory.

I could also create one Notification per recipient, but some platform providers requires me to send it in batch, meaning I need to define one Notification with several Recipients.

Each created notification could be stored in a persistent storage like a DB or Redis.

Would it be a good it to aggregate this later to make sure it is scalable?

On the second step, I need to process this notification.

But how could I distinguish the notification to the right platform provider?

Should I use an object like `MMSNotification` extending an `abstract Notification`? or something like `Notification.setType('MMS')`?

To allow to process a lot of notification at the same time, I think a messaging queue system like RabbitMQ may be the right tool. Is it?

It would allow me to queue a lot of notification and have several worker to pop notification and process them. But what if I need to batch the recipients as seen above?

Then I imagine a `NotificationProcessor` object for which I could I add `NotificationHandler` each `NotificationHandler` would be in charge to connect the platform provider and perform notification.

I can also use an `EventManager` to allow pluggable behavior.

Any feedbacks or ideas?

Thanks for giving your time.

Note: *I'm used to work in PHP and it is likely the language of my choice.*

---

**Edit** *(according to morphunreal's answer)*

- How many messages per second are you sending (Define current/initial levels, define a maximum level that the system should handle before being re-designed)
- What hardware constraints does the system have (memory, cpu etc available to the system)
- How will hardware scale (ie, adding more servers, cloud computing etc)

---

- What languages / systems will be generating notifications?

It is on my own, I'm in charge to create the notification programmatically but constructed from an UI.

- Does the generator know the recipients of the message (?) or are they provided by some other means (ie, business rules for certain alert types go to certain recipients)

It should be possible to create a notification for a specific recipients, a group of recipients (for example using a tag system), or for a whole platform.

- Are there business rules for adding CC/ BCC / Read receipts

Yes. Note that this is really platform specific and the read or cc are not available on all platforms.

- Does the generator know the type of message it's sending (ie, SMS/ email) or is it based off the recipient

It is based on the recipient, however, as the recipient is platform related, and platforms have different way to handle data, the UI is likely to be platform specific to allow to set up images, a sound or something.

- Does the generator require confirmation of messages being sent/received/read (async vs synchronous sending)

Well the system should be error prone but we would like to handle the error to define a set of rule, for example, if the server is unreachable, the notification should be requeued for further process, but if the notification is incorrect (or has been defined as is by the platform provider) it should not be requeued but notified.

- Are there requirements to store a history of message sources / recipients (how long for?)

Yes, we likely want to make some statistics and report.
* Define Notification End Points

---

- What services are being used to send messages?
  Depends, some are classical REST webservice, other are some exotic protocol, it is really up to the provider.
- What feedback / confirmation is provided (sync / async)

Depends, some are synchronous and reply with an error while some other need to be pulled afterward to check for errors.

- Is it likely to add new end-points [even if so, does it even need to be abstracted]

Yes, actually, our app is growing and we likely want to be able to add new provider, but it is a ratio of something like 1 or 2 per year.

Comment: Walter, gnat, gbjbaanb, Robert Harvey, thorsten müller seem to be lazy people ; I don't see any reason for which this question has been closed because of one of the following argument: "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical". A design question cannot be a simple question because it involves very much things, I though that the level of this website allowed such complex decision to be discussed with real professional.

Comment: Ask questions but don't ask questions! :) Yeah, sometimes I too fail to fathom the mentality of the mods.

Comment: upvotes and views show how much this question is relevant....if only moderators would have understood!!!

Comment: Using RabbitMQ is the right approach for this problem. I was asked very similar problem in one of my BIG company interview and I was struggling with the best fault tolerant  publisher/subscriber pattern. At the end I was told the correct answer. RabbitMQ. Seems like they had solved the problem using it. Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 16):

Start by separating out your functional and non-functional requirements, and carefully defining them. It's very easy to over-design a system based on ambiguous requirements.

For Example, your non-functional requirements in regards to scalability is quite ambiguous. It can relieve a lot of mental load if you put actual numbers on your system. For example,

- How many messages per second are you sending (Define current/initial levels, define a maximum level that the system should handle before being re-designed)
- What hardware constraints does the system have (memory, cpu etc available to the system)
- How will hardware scale (ie, adding more servers, cloud computing etc)

Now that you have that out of the way, you can **set up some tests** to ensure that the systems design / architecture is capable of fulfilling your non-functional requirements.

As for the business/ functional requirements of sending notifications/ messages, the following clues may help (if you provide more information I can add to this answer):

Define notification sources

- What languages / systems will be generating notifications
- Does the generator know the recipients of the message (?) or are they provided by some other means (ie, business rules for certain alert types go to certain recipients)
- Are there business rules for adding CC/ BCC / Read receipts
- Does the generator know the type of message it's sending (ie, SMS/ email) or is it based off the recipient
- Does the generator require confirmation of messages being sent/received/read (async vs synchronous sending)
- Are there requirements to store a history of message sources / recipients (how long for?)

Define Notification End Points

- What services are being used to send messages
- What feedback / confirmation is provided (sync / async)
- Is it likely to add new end-points [even if so, does it even need to be abstracted]

I'm hesitant to provide a concrete architecture example as it would depend heavily based on the factors involved; but often the simplest message systems involve a basic queue, either in memory/application, no-SQL, disk, or relational database. Then a separate process (or several separate processes if distributed) can poll the queue for their message types [ie a cron job]; and send off as necessary.

This could also be enhanced using some push-based techniques (ie PostgreSQL NOTIFY/LISTEN) if there is a requirement for messages to be sent immediately.

The advantage of a simple queue, is that the system generating the message has little work to do, and the processing system can be balanced based on hardware/performance requirements.

Comment: thank you very much for your details answer which actually help me to have some clearer ideas. I edited my answer to answer the questions you raised.

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered the flyweight design pattern for your notification objects? I am not too sure about it, since I never implemented the pattern, but I recall it involves sharing some state among the flyweight objects. I also think, the members with more redundancy had bigger impact if shared. So it depends if you send only a few msgs to a lot of people or vice versa.